# Set current date and folder on cli windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have to create a batch file but before entering a command it should display like:

```
C:\user\nameofuser AND the current date>
```

I can only display the date with `echo %date%`, but cannot make it stay on the left.

How to reach my aim?

Comment: That's trivial: see `help prompt` and guess what `$D` is for. `prompt $P$S$D$G$S`

Comment: Or if taking `C:\user\nameofuser` literal and constant (**not** changing with current dir) :  `prompt %USERPROFILE%$S$D$G$S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that, then it so easy with the `prompt` command, which defines the cmd.exe command prompt. The default is `$P` `$G`. You should change to `$P` (Current drive and path ) `$S` (space) `$D` (current date) `$G` (greater-than sign) and optionally a space with `$S`.

Changing command prompt requires the use of `prompt` command. Use `prompt $P$S$D$G$S`. The `$S` is optional.

Also, if you don't want to continuously change your prompt with the newest drive and path (not recommended), include `%userprofile%` environment variable instead of `$P`.

If you don't want the name of the date this can be done, hard of course, you may want a continuous loop, take a look at

If you don't want the date name you can see [How do I get current datetime on the Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090), but you may want a continuous loop.

Take a look below:

> `$A`  & (Ampersand)
>    `$B`   | (pipe)
>    `$C`   ( (Left parenthesis)
>    `$D`   Current date
>    `$E`   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
>    `$F`   ) (Right parenthesis)
>    `$G`   > (greater-than sign)
>    `$H`   Backspace (erases previous character)
>    `$L`   < (less-than sign)
>    `$N`   Current drive
>    `$P`   Current drive and path
>    `$Q`   = (equal sign)
>    `$S`     (space)
>    `$T`   Current time
>    `$V`   Windows version number
>    `$_`   Carriage return and linefeed
>    `$$`   $ (dollar sign)

<sup><sup>From <sup>`prompt /?`</sup> in cmd</sup></sup>